# Spring MongoDatabaseFactory - How to set mongo timeout

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data, mongotemplate

I'm working on a project whereby my spring service needs to connect to multiple Mongo DB's.

In order to achieve the ability to connect to multiple mongo db's I've created a MongoDatabaseFactory config class to represent each connection. I'am however getting random mongo SSL timeout errors. Normally when I would connect to a single mongo db I would create the client like so:

```java
  @Value("${spring.data.mongodb.host}")
    private String connectionString;

    @Bean
    public MongoClient mongoClient() {
        CodecRegistry pojoCodecRegistry = fromProviders(PojoCodecProvider.builder().automatic(true).build());
        CodecRegistry codecRegistry = fromRegistries(MongoClientSettings.getDefaultCodecRegistry(), pojoCodecRegistry);
        return MongoClients.create(MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .applyConnectionString(new ConnectionString(connectionString))
                .uuidRepresentation(UuidRepresentation.STANDARD)
                .codecRegistry(codecRegistry)
                .build());
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoClientSettings mongoClientSettings() {
        final MongoClientSettings clientSettings = MongoClientSettings.builder()
                .retryWrites(true)
                .applyToConnectionPoolSettings((ConnectionPoolSettings.Builder builder) -> {
                    builder.maxSize(300) //connections count
                            .minSize(100)
                            .maxConnectionLifeTime(300, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .maintenanceFrequency(5000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .maxConnectionIdleTime(200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .maxWaitTime(150, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                })
                .applyToSocketSettings(builder -> {
                    builder.connectTimeout(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                            .readTimeout(5500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                })

                .applicationName("TestApplication")
                .retryWrites(true)
                .build();

        return clientSettings;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoCustomConversions mongoCustomConversions() {
        return new MongoCustomConversions(Arrays.asList(
                new BigDecimalDecimal128Converter(),
                new Decimal128BigDecimalConverter()
        ));

    }

    @WritingConverter
    private static class BigDecimalDecimal128Converter implements Converter<BigDecimal, Decimal128> {

        @Override
        public Decimal128 convert(@NonNull BigDecimal source) {
            return new Decimal128(source);
        }
    }

    @ReadingConverter
    private static class Decimal128BigDecimalConverter implements Converter<Decimal128, BigDecimal> {

        @Override
        public BigDecimal convert(@NonNull Decimal128 source) {
            return source.bigDecimalValue();
        }

    }
```

And when connecting to multiple mongo db's here's how I do it:

```java
@Configuration
public class UserProfileInformationMongoConfig {
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    @Bean
    public MongoDatabaseFactory userProfileInformationFactory() {
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(new ConnectionString(env.getProperty("spring.data.mongo.userprofileinformationdb.uri")));
    }
    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate userProfileInformationMongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(userProfileInformationFactory());
    }
}
```

So, my question again is how do I set my mongo client options like in the first code example when using MongoDatabaseFactory.

Many thanks

Comment: from connection string? I don't really understand the question though

Comment: Well I'd rather set those timeout settings via MongoClientSettings than the connection string. If my question was unclear I'm sorry. Basically I normally set timeouts via MongoClientSettings. However that only works when connecting to a single Mongo DB. I have multiple db's so I need to use MongoDatabaseFactory

Answer (score 0):

Except the [`maintenanceFrequency` configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-mongodb/blob/main/spring-data-mongodb/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/MongoClientFactoryBean.java#L216), the rest can be provided in the [connection string](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/blob/master/driver-core/src/main/com/mongodb/ConnectionString.java#L114) e.g.
`mongodb://db1.example.net:27017,db2.example.net:2500/?replicaSet=test&maxPoolSize=300&minPoolSize=100&maxLifeTimeMS=300&maxIdleTimeMS=200&waitQueueTimeoutMS=150&connectTimeoutMS=2000&socketTimeoutMS=5500`

Comment: Thanks for the response. Is there no other way like how I would set it for a single mongo connection via mongoClient?